# Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ be sequences such that $ x_n$ in $[0, 1]$ and $y_n$ in $[1, 2]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Use the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem to show that there are numbers $m_1, m_2, ...$ such that $x_{m_j}$ and $y_{m_j}$ converge for j=1,2,...

So I have trouble approaching this problem. I can apply the Bolzano Weierstrass to the sequences separately to get $x_{m_k}$ converging to some $x$ and $y_{m_j}$ converging to some $y$, but this doesn't help.

I have also thought of adding $x_n$ and $y_n$ and subtracting $x_n$ and $y_n$ to get two bounded sequences each of which converges by Bolzano Weierstrass, but not sure this leads anywhere.

How do you approach this problem?

Comment: Can you apply Bolzano-Weierstrass to the sequence of ordered pairs $(x_n,y_n) \in [0,1] \times [1,2]$?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem holds not only for bounded sequences in $\Bbb R$, but also for bounded sequences in the finite-dimensional space $\Bbb R^d$. This can be seen by repeatedly picking convergent subsequences in each coordinate.

In your case ($d=2$) that would work as follows:

First apply Bolzano-Weierstrass to the (bounded) sequence $(x_n)_n$, that gives a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k$.

Then apply Bolzano-Weierstrass to the (bounded) subsequence $(y_{n_k})_k$ of $(y_n)_n$, that gives a convergent subsequence $(y_{n_{k_j}})_j$. Note that $(x_{n_{k_j}})_j$ is also convergent as a subsequence of $(x_{n_k})_k$.

Therefore, with $m_j = n_{k_j}$, $(x_{m_j})_j$ and $(y_{m_j})_j$ are “common” convergent subsequences of  $(x_n)_n$ and  $(y_n)_n$ respectively.